# Functional Programming, Haskell applying a function to a list of variables

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have a function of type `Csp -> Var -> Int -> Csp`, and I want to apply this function to a list of `[Var]`, just wondering if anyone can help me out I'm totally bamboozled!

Comment: Are the int/csp arguments supposed to be fixed, do you want to use the csp argument to iterate on or do you want the result to be a list of type [csp -> int -> csp]?

Comment: For clarification: besides the list of var, you also have a csp and an int, and you want a list of csps, is this correct?

Comment: There isn't much to go on here. Could you be more specific and add some code showing what you've tried, what results you're expecting, etc.?

Comment: i want the result to be a csp, i want to apply the function to all the the items in the list of [var] using the csp and the int, the int should stay the same but the csp should change each time the function is used on somthing in [var]

Comment: An example wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like you want a fold, for example:

```
foo :: Csp -> Var -> Int -> Csp -- your function

bar :: Csp -> [Var] -> Int -> Csp
bar c0 vs x = foldl (\c v -> foo c v x) c0 vs
```

Though it might be worth changing the order of the arguments a little to make it more suited for partial application:

```
foo :: Int -> Csp -> Var -> Csp

bar :: Int -> Csp -> [Var] -> Csp
bar x = foldl (foo x)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a fold. foldl has the signature `foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`, so in your case you want `a` to be `Csp` h and `b` to be `Var`, giving you the type `foldl :: (Csp -> Var -> Csp) -> Csp -> [Var] -> Csp`. For the first argument you just pass it something like `\csp var -> f csp var yourFixedInt` where `f` is your function.

If you aren't familiar with `fold`s what this does is apply, for each `var` in your list of `Var`s, the function you pass it (in this case just your function with the `Int` argument fixed) to a `Csp` accumulator and `var`.

(There are a lot better explanations of folds around, but I figured I'd include at least a short comment)

Answer (score 1):

http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/map_f.html

This might be what you're looking for, no?

Comment: ive tried using map, but i get this error couldn't match expected type [CSP] with inferred type CSP

Comment: OP wants to map a value onto the second argument of a three-argument function. This needs more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You want a fold, or so it sounds to me.
Suppose the function you have is `f`

```
f :: Csp -> Var -> Int -> Csp
vars = [ ..... ] :: [Var]
i :: Int -- the constant int argument to f

foldl g vars where g c v = f c v i
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a fold.

```
answer :: (Csp -> Var -> Int -> Csp) -> Csp -> [Var] -> Int -> Csp
answer f csp vs i = foldl (\csp' v -> f csp' v i) csp vs
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` takes a function and applies it to a list of values.
So as a simple example, if I have a function `f x = x + 5`, and a list `l = [1,2,3]`, then `map f l` will return `[6,7,8]`

Given `f :: Csp -> Var -> Int -> Csp`, and `l :: [Var]`, you should write

```
map (\x -> f csp x int) l -- note that the variable names (like "csp") can be anything
```

which will have the type `:: Csp -> Int -> Csp`. In other words, it will return a list of functions.