# Haskell, Applying function to each item in a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, int, fold

hey there another haskell question i have a function of type 
   f :: CSP -> Assignment -> Var -> Int -> CSP

i want to write a function with the type

g :: CSP -> Assignment -> Var -> [Int] -> CSP

which applies the original function to all of the elements in the list `[Int]`. The `CSP` that it is passed should be updated each time `f` is applied, the `Assigment` will stay the same as will the `Var`. I'm pretty sure I need to use a fold but I really don't understand them.  I'd really appreciate it if somebody could help me out and maybe try and explain folds.

Comment: This looks a lot like homework - is it?

Comment: it's not homework, but i got it sorted anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functional Programming, Haskell applying a function to a list of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398085/functional-programming-haskell-applying-a-function-to-a-list-of-variables)

Answer (score 2):

You said you've worked it out, but just in case:

```
g c a v is = foldl (\c i -> f c a v i) c is
```